# Stuck on "Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source (i386)" while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, kernel, 32-bit

So, as the title says, installation get stuck while Configuring that package. Now, I am aware that this question has already been asked, but the solution requires internet connection and I don't have one on that Laptop (for reasons that I wont be saying now. It's just to complicated to explain so just assume that there is no way to connect to the internet with that Laptop for now :) )

Laptop is Acer Aspire 5570Z (5572ZWXMi) with 32bit CPU. Image is also 32bit ;) It's not corrupted, and it's properly transferred onto a USB stick using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.5. I tried installing again and again, but it always get stuck here.
Here is a copy of the code (I, of course, couldn't copy/paste so I hope it helps :D)

```
Oct 9 02:36:26 ubuntu ubiquity: Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Oct 9 02:36:26 ubuntu ubiquity: (Reading database ... 174157 files and directories currently installed.)
Oct 9 02:36:27 ubuntu ubiquity: Preparing to unpack .../dkmms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Oct 9 02:36:27 ubuntu ubiquity: Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5) ...
Oct 9 02:36:28 ubuntu ubiquity: Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
Oct 9 02:36:28 ubuntu ubiquity: Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_i386.deb ...)
Oct 9 02:36:28 ubuntu ubiquity: Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2)
Oct 9 02:36:29 ubuntu ubiquity: Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:i386.
Oct 9 02:36:29 ubuntu ubiquity: Preparing to unpack .../libfakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Oct 9 02:36:29 ubuntu ubiquity: Unpacking libfakeroot:i386 (1.20-3ubuntu2)
Oct 9 02:36:30 ubuntu ubiquity: Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Oct 9 02:36:30 ubuntu ubiquity: Preparing to unpack .../fakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Oct 9 02:36:30 ubuntu ubiquity: Unpacking fakeroot (1.20-3ubuntu2)
Oct 9 02:36:30 ubuntu ubiquity: Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1)
Oct 9 02:36:38 ubuntu ubiquity: Setting up dkms(2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5)
Oct 9 02:36:38 ubuntu ubiquity: Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2)
Oct 9 02:36:38 ubuntu ubiquity: Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.121+bdcom DKMS files...
Oct 9 02:36:38 ubuntu ubiquity: First Installation: checking all kernels...
Oct 9 02:36:38 ubuntu ubiquity: Building only for 3.13.0-32-generic
Oct 9 02:36:39 ubuntu ubiquity: Building for architecture i686
Oct 9 02:36:39 ubuntu ubiquity: Building initial module for 3.13.0-32-generic
Oct 9 02:36:54 ubuntu ubiquity: Done. 
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity:
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity: wl:
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity: Running module version sanity check.
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity:   - Original module
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity:    - No original module exists within this kernel
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity:   - Installation
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity:    - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity:
Oct 9 02:36:55 ubuntu ubiquity: depmod...
Oct 9 02:36:58 ubuntu ubiquity: .
Oct 9 02:37:07 ubuntu ubiquity: message repeated 3 times: [ .]
Oct 9 02:37:07 ubuntu ubiquity:
Oct 9 02:37:07 ubuntu ubiquity:
Oct 9 02:37:07 ubuntu ubiquity: DKMS: install completed.
Oct 9 03:17:01 ubuntu CRON[22111]: (root) CMD (    cd / && run-parts -- report /etc/cron.hourly)
```